# Toolbar disappearing when loading page upside down

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, rotation, portrait

So this will almost certainly be a simple answer, but I can't for the life of me work it out!

Basically, I want my current app to be viewable in portrait only (for now at least) and either the right way up, or upside down. Everything works fine the right way up and when you rotate the iPad on a page, everything works fine, the page flips up as normal. But if you hold the iPad upside down (home button at the top) and click a button to load a new page, when the page loads the toolbar is not visible! I don't know if for some reason the toolbar is behind the rest of the content or if its not there. If you then rotate the iPad back to portrait, the toolbar appears and all is back to normal again!

Whats weirder is that on the iPhone, the toolbar is there when you load a page with an upside down iPhone!!

I've tried all sorts with the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation() and didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation() methods and with resizing/positioning on viewDidLoad depending on the orientation. But nothing seems to work at all!!

This is code I have in my viewDidLoad() method:

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
    NSLog(@"iPhone");
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
    {
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
    }
    else if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 460);
    }
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"iPad");
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
    {
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024);
        NSLog(@"iPad Portrait Up");
    }
    else if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 768, 1024);
        NSLog(@"iPad Portrait Upside Down");
    }
}
```

I've tried similar things in the didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation() method but nothing is working!

Thanks in advance for any help and feel free to ask questions/request more code

Matt

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar problem and here is what I discovered. When You add a toolbar at the top of the iPad UIView xib file, its autosizing is default to set up as shown in figure below. The toolbar will always stick to the bottom instead of the top.

[image]

What I did is change it to stick to top as shown in figure below and it fixed my problem.

[image]

If you setup the toolbar programmatically, you need to update the autoresizingMask.

Comment: This seems like it may work! I haven't had chance to test it yet, but will do as soon as I can! Thanks in advance! :D